# WP Insert post with post_thumbnail

Tags: custom-field, post-thumbnails, wp-insert-post

Insert post thumbnail with '**wp_insert_post**', i'm trying this code but does not work, the field '**get_field('imagem_do_produto')** returns the url of the image, why not work?

```
<?php $exists = get_page_by_title( get_field('fornecedor'), OBJECT, 'fornecedores');
    if(empty($exists)){
        $insert_post = array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'fornecedores', // post_type which is created posting
            'post_title' => get_field('fornecedor'), // Custom field to generate the post type
            'post_thumbnail' => get_field('imagem_do_produto') // returns URL of image for feature image
        );
        wp_insert_post($insert_post);
    }
?>
```

he code creates the post, but only the title or content.
I wanted to add a highlighted image for this post to be created.

tnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a thumbnail for product you can't pass the argument `post_thumbnail` to `wp_insert_post` it does nothing.

The right way is to use the wp function [`set_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail). Problem is that to use this function you need the ID of the image, not the url.

Once you in your code use `get_field` I assumed that you are using [ACF plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), and that the field `imagem_do_produto` in an ['image' field type](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/image/) that upload images in media library and, by default, save the url as custom field.

That field can be configured to save the **image id**, that it's better for your scope, but once you say that it contain an url you need to get the image id from its url.
A rapid google search let me find a good solution for that [**here**](http://philipnewcomer.net/2012/11/get-the-attachment-id-from-an-image-url-in-wordpress/).

Now we can use the function we find and put it in `functions.php`, then make use of it in combination with `set_post_thumbnail` to assign the thumbnail to the newly created post.

```
<?php

// this function should go in functions.php
// and is not needed if your imagem_do_produto is configured to save the ID
function image_id_from_url( $attachment_url = '' ) {
  if ( empty($attachment_url) || ! filter_var($thumb, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ) )
    return false;
  $upload_dir_paths = wp_upload_dir();
  if ( ! substr_count($attachment_url, $upload_dir_paths['baseurl']) )
    return false;
  $attachment_id = false;
  $attachment_url = preg_replace( '/-\d+x\d+(?=\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$)/i', '', $attachment_url );
  $attachment_url = str_replace( $upload_dir_paths['baseurl'] . '/', '', $attachment_url );
  global $wpdb;
  $attachment_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT wposts.ID FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
    AND wpostmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
    AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '%s'
    AND wposts.post_type = 'attachment'",
    $attachment_url
  ) );
  return $attachment_id;
}
```

If you configure your image field to save the image id instead of the url, the function above is not needed.

```
$exists = get_page_by_title( get_field('fornecedor'), OBJECT, 'fornecedores');
$postid = '';
if( empty($exists) ) {
  $insert_post = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'fornecedores',
    'post_title' => get_field('fornecedor'),
  );
  $postid = wp_insert_post($insert_post);
}
if ( ! empty($postid) ) {
   // if you configure the field 'imagem_do_produto' to save image id
   // replace next 2 lines with only one:
   // $thumbnail_id = get_field('imagem_do_produto');
   $thumbnail_url = get_field('imagem_do_produto');
   $thumbnail_id = image_id_from_url( $thumbnail_url );

   if ( $thumbnail_id > 0 ) set_post_thumbnail( $postid, $thumbnail_id );
}
```

Comment: Yes friend, the image field comes from the plugin 'ACF', I configured to return the ID of the image and run, just changed the line `$thumbnail_id = get_field('imagem_do_produto');` thank you for helping me.

Comment: Good. So in this case you don't need the `image_id_from_url` function.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the code from functions.php, but leaves the code here in case anyone needs it, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

`post_thumbnail` is not a valid parameter for [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post#Parameters).

To set the thumbnail, you need to use [`set_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail) with the post ID returned from `wp_insert_post` and the attachment ID for the image to attach, but your code would need some refactoring to do that. And I can't quite tell exactly what you have happening.

You already have an image URL. It that is an image that has been uploaded by the WordPress media system (to the Library) you could back out the ID from the URL you have, though there may be better ways depending on details you have not posted.

If you are trying to use some other image-- one not uploaded to the library, for example-- you are better off just using the URL you already have directly. That is, just edit the template to use that URL as a thumbnail the way it had to be done before the WordPress Core included "Featured" image functionality.